# Unable to understand the behaviour of reword flag during git interactive rebase

Tags: git, git-rebase

I have few questions related to `git interactive rebase`. 
First I created a git repository on my local machine and performed 5 commits.

1. When I hit `git rebase -i HEAD~5` I get the below error

   ```
   fatal: Needed a single revision
   invalid upstream HEAD~5
   ```

   I do not understand the reason for the above error
2. When I get to the rebase interactive shell, I tried the reword option using the `r` flag and provided the updated message. When I tried to save and exit it launched another terminal to pass the commit message. I am missing something. Can someone educate me on the behaviour.

Comment: use '--root' for your git rebase.

Comment: @Andrew what is that root option for?

Comment: Concerning (2), it did exactly what you asked for. Changing the text next to the `r` flag doesn't have an effect (I'm regularly falling for that as well, though).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fundamentally, rebase works by *copying* commits.  For instance, suppose you have the four commits I've labeled as `A` through `D` below and you want to rebase `branch` onto `mainline`:

```
...--o--o--T   <-- mainline
      \
       A--B--C--D   <-- branch (HEAD)
```

What `git rebase mainline` will do is *copy* `A` to a new commit `A'` that is "like `A`, but just as good or better":

```
             A'   <-- temporary (HEAD)
            /
...--o--o--T   <-- mainline
      \
       A--B--C--D   <-- branch
```

The difference between `A` and `A'` is that `A'` has `T`, the tip of `mainline`, as its parent commit.  (Plus it has any other changes you care to make to it, if you use an interactive rebase.)

Once `A` is copied to `A'`, `git rebase` goes on to copy `B`, and then `C` and `D`.  Ultimately, the result is:

```
             A'-B'-C'-D'   <-- temporary (HEAD)
            /
...--o--o--T   <-- mainline
      \
       A--B--C--D   <-- branch
```

Now that all commits are copied, `git rebase` "peels off" the old branch label `branch` and moves it to replace the temporary branch name:

```
             A'-B'-C'-D'   <-- branch (HEAD)
            /
...--o--o--T   <-- mainline
      \
       A--B--C--D   [abandoned]
```

The argument you pass to `git rebase` is a name for the commit you want the copies to go after.  In this case, the name `mainline` names commit `T`, so the copies go after `T`.

Now that you know this, and noting that `HEAD~5` means "count back five steps" from HEAD, we can explain your issues:

> `git rebase -i HEAD~5` [fails]

Suppose you have *only* five commits in the chain to be copied:

```
A--B--C--D--E   <-- master
```

where `A` has no *parent* commit, i.e., is the *root* commit.  `HEAD` names commit `E`.  `HEAD~1` names `D`, `HEAD~2` names `C`, and so on.  What commit is `HEAD~5`?

*There is no commit before `A`*.  `git rebase` is normally used to copy commits *after* some existing commit, but if you want to copy `A` itself, how will you name the commit before `A` that the copy should go after, and let `rebase` start copying from commit `A`?

This is where `--root` comes in: `git rebase --root` allows you to copy `A` itself.  Git uses a number of special tricks to do this, and the end result is an independent chain of copies:

```
A--B--C--D--E   [abandoned]

A'-B'-C'-D'-E'  <-- master
```

> When I get to the rebase interactive shell, I tried the reword option using the `r` flag and provided the updated message. When I tried to save and exit it launched another terminal to pass the commit message.

All `reword` or `r` does is modify the copying process: Git still copies the commits, one at a time, to the new ones, but when it goes to make the copy of the "reword" commit, it fires up a `git commit --edit` rather than a `git commit --no-edit`.  This brings up your editor on the original commit message, which you can now reword.

The instruction sheet that you are editing initially does not let you change an entire commit message, because commit messages are (or should be) more than just a single line.  So it ends up completely *ignoring* any other changes you make, other than changing the command from `pick`.

The new editor session is just for the one particular commit.

(More precisely, the command `pick <hash>` literally means *run `git cherry-pick` on the given hash.  The hash ID must be valid.  If you re-arrange the lines in the instruction sheet, you re-arrange the order of `git cherry-pick` commands that the interactive rebase runs.  If you delete or comment out a line, Git simply never cherry-picks that particular commit.  Using `reword` instead of `pick` just makes the cherry-pick commit interactive, rather than fully automated.)